# Compute statistics based on grouping of data.frame

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I have the following data.frame that I'd like to compute a few statistics for:

```
       gene_symbol signal_window signal_score MEF_chRNA     ES_chRNA signal_dist_to_gene
262764        GOT1        218220         0.08 0.2696089 0.3356937140               44805
403001        NKX2        218220         0.08 0.0000000 0.0008852885               42915
262630        GOT1        218221         0.08 0.2696089 0.3356937140               45005
403039        NKX2        218221         0.08 0.0000000 0.0008852885               42715
262793        GOT1        218222         0.00 0.2696089 0.3356937140               45205
402663        NKX2        218222         0.00 0.0000000 0.0008852885               42515
262867        GOT1        218223         0.16 0.2696089 0.3356937140               45405
402737        NKX2        218223         0.16 0.0000000 0.0008852885               42315
262677        GOT1        218224         0.16 0.2696089 0.3356937140               45605
403006        NKX2        218224         0.16 0.0000000 0.0008852885               42115
262858        GOT1        218225         0.16 0.2696089 0.3356937140               45805
402953        NKX2        218225         0.16 0.0000000 0.0008852885               41915
```

As shown in the example data.frame, there can be multiple `gene_symbol` values for each `signal_window`. Now, for each `gene_symbol` within each `signal_window` I'd like to compute `1/signal_dist_to_gene`. I want to use this value to compute the sum of each `1/signal_dist_to_gene` for each `gene_symbol` within each `signal_window`.

For example, for window 218220 there are two genes. For each gene I want to compute:

```
gene_weight_GOT1 = (1/signal_dist_to_gene_GOT1) / (1/signal_dist_to_gene_GOT1 + 1/signal_dist_to_gene_NKX2)
gene_weight_NKX2 = (1/signal_dist_to_gene_NKX2) / (1/signal_dist_to_gene_GOT1 + 1/signal_dist_to_gene_NKX2)
```

I ultimately want to use these `gene_weight` variables to compute:

```
MEF_prop = [MEF_chRNA_GOT1 * gene_weight_GOT1 * 1/2 + MEF_chRNA_NKX2 * gene_weight_NKX2 * 1/2] / [gene_weight_GOT1 * (MEF_chRNA_GOT1/2 + ES_chRNA_GOT1/2) + gene_weight_NKX2 * (MEF_chRNA_NKX2/2 + ES_chRNA_NKX2/2)]
```

There is no garentee that there will always be 2 genes in the same window. There are cases where there are no genes (NA) and other where there are 20+ genes. **Is there an easy way to compute this using plyr or dplyr?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ought to do it. First we group by the signal_window, then calculate the weights as you specified. The `sum` in the denominator is calculated over the group (signal_window)

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  group_by(signal_window) %>%
  mutate(gene_weight = (1 / signal_dist_to_gene) / sum(1/signal_dist_to_gene))
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard [dplyr](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.2/topics/group_by) syntax `data.df %>% group_by() %>% mutate()`should be pretty straight forward for what you're attempting.

Your code might end up looking something like this:

```
data.df %>% 
group_by(signal_window, gene_symbol) %>% 
mutate(gene_weight = (1/signal_dist_to_gene) / sum(1/signal_dist_to_gene)) %>%
mutate(MEF_prop = (MEF_chRNA * gene_weight * 1/2 + MEF_chRNA * gene_weight * 1/2) / (gene_weight * (MEF_chRNA/2 + ES_chRNA/2) + gene_weight * (MEF_chRNA/2 + ES_chRNA/2)))
```

You can drop `gene_symbol` from `group_by` if you want each duplicate symbol to be treated uniquely within `signal_window`, or leave it in if you want them grouped.

Is that what you're after?